# Problemas con funcion attr

Tags: jquery

no me agrega el atributo disabled al select

lo que esta en php es esto

```
 <div class="input-field col s2 ">
                     <select id="mododepagofacturaguardar">
                      <option value="0" disabled selected></option>';

                    foreach($respuesta2 as $row2 => $item2) {

                     echo '
                      <option value="'.$item2["id_modopago"].'">'.$item2["modopago"].'</option>
                    ';

                }

      echo '</select>
                    <label>Modo De Pago</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s2 ">
                     <select id="selectorinides" >
                      <option value="0" disabled selected></option>
                      <option value="1" >CUOTA INICIAL</option>
                      <option value="2">DESCUENTO</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>SELECCIONA</label>
                    </div>
```

lo que esta en js es esto

```
$( function() {
    $("#mododepagofacturaguardar").change( function() {

      variable=$(this).val();
      console.log(variable);
        if (variable === "1") {
         $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#selectorinides").val();
             $("#selectorinides").attr("disabled");
                    $('select').formSelect();
  });
        } else {
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#selectorinides").removeAttr('disabled');
             $('select').formSelect();
  });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Que tal Alberto, Debes pasarle que valor va a tener la propiedad disabled por ejemplo .attr("disabled",true); o .attr("disabled","disabled");

Comment: usa como ya te respondieron o te comentaron con "attr" o con "prop"...o si prefieres usar javascript puro: document.getElementById('ejemplo').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');

Comment: Tu mejor aliado en estos casos es la documentación de jquery, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

**EDIT**: para que funcione con materialize

```
$("#selectorinides").prop("disabled", true).formSelect();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.select').formSelect();

  $(".test").click(function(){
    if(!$(".select").prop('disabled')){
      $(".select").prop("disabled", true).formSelect()
    }else
      $(".select").prop("disabled", false).formSelect();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<button class="test">disable/enable</button>

<select class="select">
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

En ocaciones es necesario agregar el change para que se refleje los cambios

```js
$("#selectorinides").prop("disabled", true).change();
```